# RxJS - emit only if other does not emit during delay

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Suppose I have two observables. Every time the first one emits, I want to wait 2 seconds to see whether during that period the other observable emits something. If yes, do not emit anything. If no, emit.

Example:

```
const start$ = this.events.pipe(
  delay(1000),
  takeUntil(theSecondObservable) // WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?
).subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: Your sample is working as I understand your problem, I don't get it, what is your question ? actually you have "start$" and "theSecondObservable" which are observable , and your "start$" actually will emit after the delay AND only if "theSecondObservable" didn't emit anything

Comment: That is correct but I want it to happen that way every time start emits something. This way, take until completes the observable and nothing will happen. Is it clear now? Thank you,

Comment: Please add that clarification to your post by using "edit" below your post (though I think you meant "... every time this.events emits something ...", not "... every time start emits something ..."). Please further clarify: do you really want to delay the primary event or was that just your attempt of solving the problem? For example: do you want to actually emit as soon as possible if there was no blocking event within 1000ms (2000ms)? You might also want to draw an ASCII art diagram/timeline.

Comment: Is the question clear now? I also submitted my final solution that I was able to make with the partial answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the help of the answers above. However, they did not completely answer my question and there might be a better way. My solution:

```
const end$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  map(() => false),
);
const start$ = this.router.events.pipe(
  map(() => true),
);

merge(
  end$,
  start$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => {
      return race(end$, of(true).pipe(delay(2000)));
    }),
    filter((value) => value === true) // this really works only with booleans, not sure how I'd do it with more 
                                                            // complex objects
  )
).subscribe((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: It looks like merge will still emit false values from end$.

Answer (score 2):

This solution does not complete when the end$ observable emits and uses RxJS 6 syntax.

```
const start$ = this.router.events.pipe(map(() => true));
const end$ = this.router.events.pipe(map(() => false));

merge(start$, end$)
  .pipe(debounceTime(2000), filter(value => value))
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

If you're filtering router events you may not need two observables.

```
this.router.events
  .pipe(debounceTime(2000), filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [race operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/race.html).

```
const start$ = race(this.events.pipe(delay(1000)), theSecondObservable).subscribe(value => /** ... */);
```

Once one of the observables emits an object, the other observable will be ignored and only values emitted by the 'winner' will be passed on to the subscriber. In your subscription function, you can perform some logic to figure out which observable your value came from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you interesting in limiting the emitions from the 1st observer or just in the end result?

You can use a race...

```
let r = race(observer1.pipe(delay(2000)), observer2)
 // r will emmit from observer1 only if observer2 didnt emmit, else it will emmit from observer2
```