# Emit from an observable only if another observable hasn't emitted in the last two seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, animation, rxjs

Note: Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53906200/rxjs-emit-only-if-other-does-not-emit-during-delay) but it doesn't seem to be answered in an obvious way I can apply.

Problem: I have a 'go to top' button whose function is to scroll the user to the top of the page. It should not be visible when the user is actually at the top.

Its visibility is presently handled via an animated opacity attribute, but it is able to be interacted with due to display: none not being applied. So I must find a way to have display: none apply when the opacity is 0.

The first implementation, in Angular, is to do something like this:

```
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    scrolled(_event: Event) {
        if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
            setTimeout(() => (this.noClick = true), 1000);
        } else {
            this.noClick = false;
        }

        this.show = window.pageYOffset > 0;
    }
```

Where `noClick` and `show` are boolean values, and `noClick` is applied to a class which sets display:none and `show` is applied to the animated opacity.

There is a race condition however, where the user can scroll down after scrolling to 0 and the delay can still set `noClick` to true.

I would like to consider an Observable to solve this issue.

If I have two subjects:

```
displayNone = new Subject<boolean>();   // only contains true values
displaySome = new Subject<boolean>();   // only contains false values
```

and some event code:

```
    @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
    scrolled(_event: Event) {
        if (window.pageYOffset === 0) {
            this.displayNone.next(true);
        } else {
            this.displaySome.next(false);
        }

        this.show = window.pageYOffset > 0;
    }
```

I need to construct an observable for the `displayNone` functionality where if `displayNone` is delayed 1000ms (animation time) and in that time `displaySome` emits, it must ignore `displayNone`.

The closest that I can come presently is something like this:

```
race(this.displaySome, this.displayNone.pipe(delay(1000)))
```

But my understanding is that it will take only evaluate it once and make a decision which one to pass through. I need it to be constantly evaluated.

Comment: What purpose does the 1000ms delay serve?

Comment: Also, can you create a simple stackblitz demonstrating the problem

Comment: Its very unclear to me why you have two Subjects. It looks like you could have just one emitting `true`/`false` depending on whether you want to show the button or not. Or maybe there's something I don't see...

Comment: @KurtHamilton the 1000ms delay was the duration of animation on the opacity property because the display: none doesn't animate.

Comment: @martin the two subjects are because one of them has to be delayed to give time for the animation to work and the other should override it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need two Observables to show/hide a button with animations. The best solution to your problem is different from the answer to your question. I'm trying to answer both.

### Only emit if another Observable hasn't emitted in the last X milliseconds

```ts
const X = 1000;
const obs$ = source$.pipe(
  // emit values on a new inner Observable when the otherObservable$ emits
  window(otherObservable$),
  // skip all values on this inner Observable until a given time has passed
  // (but not for the first inner Observable created before otherObservable$ emits)
  mergeMap((w, i) => i == 0 ? w : w.pipe(skipUntil(timer(X))))
);
```

### Show/hide a Button depending on scroll events

1. Create an Observable from scroll events and map to a boolean value indicating whether to show or hide the button.

```ts
hasScrolledDown$: Observable<boolean>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.hasScrolledDown$ = fromEvent(window, 'scroll').pipe(
    throttleTime(20),
    map(() => window.pageYOffset > 50)
  )
}
```

2. Use `ngIf` to show / hide the button depending on the value from the Observable.

```html
<button *ngIf="hasScrolledDown$ | async">
```

3. *(Optional)* Add animations for `enter` and `leave` state changes.

```html
<button *ngIf="hasScrolledDown$ | async" [@fadeAnimation]>
```

```ts
export const fadeOutAnimation = animation([
    style({ opacity: 1 }),
    animate('200ms', style({ opacity: 0 }))
])

export const fadeInAnimation = animation([
    style({ opacity: 0 }),
    animate('200ms', style({ opacity: 1 }))
])

@Component({
  selector: 'button-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'button-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['button-overview-example.css'],
  animations: [
    trigger('fadeAnimation', [
      transition(':enter', [useAnimation(fadeInAnimation)]),
      transition(':leave', [useAnimation(fadeOutAnimation)])
    ])
  ],
})
```

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-41wv3d-fvfpsv)

Comment: This solution worked perfectly, thank you for answering the real problem. Although I am still curious about the observables question.

Comment: @JeffreyDrake I added an answer to the question from your title.